# 'textstat_readability' is not an exported object from 'namespace:quanteda'

Tags: quanteda

I am a new user (in R and quanteda) and this is the first time that I am trying to use liwcalike. It also happens to be my first post on stackoverflow. So, really new! Maybe a basic question, but here is the code:

```
txt <- c("The red-shirted lawyer gave her yellow-haired, red nose ex-boyfriend $300
            out of pity:(.")
dict <- quanteda::dictionary(list(people = c("lawyer", "boyfriend"),
                                  color_fixed = "red",
                                  color_glob = c("red*", "yellow*", "green*"),
                                  mwe = "out of"))

liwcalike(txt, dict, what = "word")
```

When I try to run my R code on R studio, this is the error I get on using liwcalike.

'textstat_readability' is not an exported object from 'namespace:quanteda'

I wonder what is that is wrong in my code?
The quanteda version is 3.1.1.

Any inputs appreciated.

Thanks,

JC

Comment: Sorry. I just restarted R after reinstalling quanteda, and it works now! Apologies for the basic question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author answered it themselves right after asking.